# Powermock ProcessBuilder constructor with String[].class argument

Tags: junit, constructor, mockito, powermock

When I tried to powermock the `ProcessBuilder` constructor, it successes if the argument is an `ArrayList`, but it fails when the argument is a `String` array.

The class to be tested is:

```java
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MockProcessBuilder {

    public void instance1() throws Exception {

        String chmodCmd[] = { "/bin/chmod", "755", "/path/to/dest" + "/" + "file.txt" };

        // constructor with String[].class
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(chmodCmd);

        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);

        Process proc = pb.start();

        proc.waitFor();
    }

    public void instance2() throws Exception {

        ArrayList<String> cmdArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        cmdArrayList.add("/bin/execScript");
        cmdArrayList.add("exec");
        cmdArrayList.add("ls -altr");

        // constructor with ArrayList.class             
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmdArrayList);

        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);

        Process proc = pb.start();

        proc.waitFor();
    }
}
```

The test class is:

```java
package test;

import static org.mockito.Matchers.isA;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({MockProcessBuilder.class, ProcessBuilder.class})
public class MockProcessBuilderTest {

    @Mock ProcessBuilder pb;
    @Mock Process proc;

    // fail. NullPointerException
    @Test
    public void testInstance1() throws Exception {

        PowerMockito.whenNew(ProcessBuilder.class).withParameterTypes(String[].class).withArguments(isA(String[].class)).thenReturn(pb);
        Mockito.when(pb.start()).thenReturn(proc);

        MockProcessBuilder mpb = new MockProcessBuilder();

        mpb.instance1();
    }

    // success
    @Test
    public void testInstance2() throws Exception {

        PowerMockito.whenNew(ProcessBuilder.class).withParameterTypes(List.class).withArguments(isA(ArrayList.class)).thenReturn(pb);
        Mockito.when(pb.start()).thenReturn(proc);

        MockProcessBuilder mpb = new MockProcessBuilder();

        mpb.instance2();
    }
}
```

The first test case fails with error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Could anyone know how to mock the first constructor?

Thanks

***EDIT***
full trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at test.MockProcessBuilder.instance1(MockProcessBuilder.java:14)
at test.MockProcessBuilderTest.testInstance1(MockProcessBuilderTest.java:32)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:88)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:96)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:86)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:33)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:45)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:118)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:101)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:53)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: What's the full stacktrace? What line is it pointing you to? I guarantee you the JVM is not lying when it says there is a null pointer on that line.

Comment: @MattLachman, thanks for your reply. I added the full trace above.

Comment: It looks as if the argument doesn't make it into the `public OngoingStubbing<T> withArguments(Object firstArgument, Object... additionalArguments)` method in `DefaultConstructurExpectationSetup` inside the `Mockito` framework but I haven't been able to track down why. Hopefully this info will help track it down.

Comment: Interesting, I'm seeing the same thing with PowerMockito and ProcessBuilder. I change my code from `ProcessBuilder(String[])` to `ProcessBuilder(List<String>)` so I could test it.

Answer (score 1):

The testInstance1() test is failing because the argument matcher `isA(String[].class)` doesn't match the String varargs arguments that you're giving. To make the test pass, replace the testInstance1() line

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(ProcessBuilder.class).withParameterTypes(String[].class).
             withArguments(isA(String[].class)).thenReturn(pb);
```

with

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(ProcessBuilder.class).withParameterTypes(String[].class).
             withArguments(anyVararg()).thenReturn(pb);
```

Powermock is intercepting the call to the ProcessBuilder varargs constructor due to `PowerMockito.whenNew(ProcessBuilder.class).withParameterTypes(String[].class)` matching the varargs constructor. However, because `withArguments(isA(String[].class))` does not match, the thenReturn gets ignored and Powermock just returns null instead of the pb mock.

See also [How to properly match varargs in Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631596/how-to-properly-match-varargs-in-mockito)