# Mockito ArgumentMatcher any Object[]

Tags: java, spring, mockito, argument-matcher

I need an ArgumentMatcher accepting any type of values in an Object array (Object[]).
TestObject:

```
class ObjectArrayMethod {
    public int call(Object... objects) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I tried these, where all assertEquals are failing:

```
    ObjectArrayMethod method = Mockito.mock(ObjectArrayMethod.class);

    Object[] arg = {"", ""};
    Mockito.when(method.call(AdditionalMatchers.aryEq(arg))).thenReturn(15);
    int actual = method.call(arg);
    assertEquals(15, actual);

    ObjectArrayMethod method = Mockito.mock(ObjectArrayMethod.class);

    Mockito.when(method.call(any(Object[].class))).thenReturn(15);
    Object[] arg = new Object[] {null, null};
    int actual = method.call(arg);
    assertEquals(15, actual);
```

even failing:

```
    ObjectArrayMethod method = Mockito.mock(ObjectArrayMethod.class);

    Object[] arg = {"", ""};
    Mockito.when(method.call(AdditionalMatchers.aryEq(arg))).thenReturn(15);
    int actual = method.call(arg);
    assertEquals(15, actual);
```

I wrote an own Matcher:

```
    protected static class ObjectArrayArgumentMatcher implements ArgumentMatcher<Object[]>, VarargMatcher {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3846783742617041128L;
    private final Object[] values;
    private ErrorState errorState = NO_ERROR;

    protected ObjectArrayArgumentMatcher(Object[] values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object[] argument) {

        if (values == null) {
            return true;
        }

        if (argument == null) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

and

```
    protected static class ObjectArrayArgumentMatcher2 extends ObjectArrayArgumentMatcher {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3085412884910289910L;

    protected ObjectArrayArgumentMatcher2(Object... values) {
        super(values);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object... argument) {
        return super.matches(argument);
    }

}
```

Which I initialize with null values. But I's not called.

Of cause the next step is to compare arguments.

Why is neighter  matches(Object[] argument) nor  matches(Object... argument) called, with args {"", ""} or even {null, null}?

What I need is an ArgumentMatcher, that works for any Object array, even with mixed types like {"String", 1, new Object()}.

The method I finally want to mock is

```
int org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(String sql, Object... args) throws DataAccessException
```

I am using

```
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
```

Btw. with Version 1.10.19 my ObjectArrayArgumentMatcher worked.

Comment: Though your question title seems to be simply answered with [`anyVararg()`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.22.0/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#anyVararg--) (deprecated in favor of `any` since 2.2), your question body may be better-answered with [this other SO question about `eq` applying to varargs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24295197/1426891). If that's sufficient please respond and I'll mark this question as a duplicate of that one. (Also, be careful: `==` only checks _reference equality_ on the array reference, not its contents.) Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. A similar post was prototype for my ObjectArrayArgumentMatcher. It doesn't work in mockito 2.22.0 anymore. ArgumentMatcher is an interface now, and the matches Method is generic.

Comment: At least someone mocked successfully int org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(String sql, Object... args), returning a 1 on calls?

Comment: @JeffBowman: Actually it is a duplicate as you suggested. I just didn't get the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally this post helped me for the solution:
[How to properly match varargs in Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631596/how-to-properly-match-varargs-in-mockito)

This works:

```
Mockito.when(method.call(ArgumentMatchers.<Object>any())).thenReturn(10);
```