# Access varargs of a stubbed method to return different results

Tags: java, mockito

I want to mock a class which has a varargs parameter method. Based on [is there Mockito eq matcher for varargs array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24295197/is-there-mockito-eq-matcher-for-varargs-array/24295695#24295695) I came up with the following but the ArgumentMatcher is not called at all.

My class to mock:

```
public class ProcessUtil {
  public Result execute(String... commandParts) throws Exception { ... }
}
```

My class to test (`InstallService`) executes a couple of `ProcessUtil.execute()` and I want to return different Results based on the varargs of the call. Therefor I created this ArgumentMatcher:

```
class StringVarArgsMatcher implements ArgumentMatcher<String[]>,VarargMatcher {

    private String[] expectedValues;

    StringVarArgsMatcher(String... expectedValues) {
        this.expectedValues = expectedValues;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(String[] arguments) {
        boolean matched = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < expectedValues.length; i++) {
            matched = "".equals(expectedValues[i]) || arguments[i].endsWith(expectedValues[i]);
        }

        return matched;
    }
}
```

My test is constructed this way:

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception{
    ProcessUtil processUtilMock = mock(ProcessUtil.class);
    ProcessUtil.Result installCommandResult = new ProcessUtil.Result(Collections.emptyList(), Collections.emptyList());
    when(processUtilMock.execute(argThat(new StringVarArgsMatcher(new String[]{"", "", "", "", "--install"})))).thenReturn(installCommandResult);

    InstallService installService = new InstallService(processUtilMock);
    boolean databaseInstalled = installService.installDatabase();
    Assert.assertFalse(databaseInstalled);
}
```

When I run my test it seems that the ArgumentMatcher is not called at all. If I set any breakpoint inside of the matcher execution will not stop. My `InstallService` will also get a NullPointer-Exception when it tries to evaluate the Result of `ProcessUtil.execute()`

What is it that I am missing?

Comment: I deleted my old workaround and added the solution for your problem. Its easier than I thought it would be, but for that you have to understand how mockito actually applies the matcher ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `StringVarArgsMatcher` to implement `ArgumentMatcher<String>` instead of the string array.

When mockito identifies the matcher as a varargs matcher (by relying on the `VarargMatcher` interface), it matches each argument **individually** against your matcher.

You will have to adjust your matcher for this, for example:

```java
class StringVarArgsMatcher implements ArgumentMatcher<String>,VarargMatcher {

    private String[] expectedValues;
    private int count = 0;

    StringVarArgsMatcher(String... expectedValues) {
        this.expectedValues = expectedValues;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(String argument) {

        if (count >= expectedValues.length) {
            return false;
        }

        boolean result = "".equals(expectedValues[count]) || argument.endsWith(expectedValues[count]);
        count++;
        return result; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from [second](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58992961/3826728) correctly answers the question about varargs and ArgumentMatcher, but I realized that for my described problem it's the wrong approach. The culprit is this:

> My class to test (InstallService) executes a *couple of* ProcessUtil.execute() and I want to *return different Results*

Chaining `thenReturn()` in combination with ArgumentMatcher may help but is kind of inflexible when the internals of `InstallService` change in the future.

My solution uses `thenAnswer()`.

```
when(processUtilMock.execute(any())).thenAnswer( invocation -> {
    Object[] arguments = invocation.getArguments();

    ProcessUtil.Result result = null;
    String lastArgument = (String) arguments[arguments.length-1];
    switch (lastArgument) {
        case "1":
            result = new ProcessUtil.Result(Collections.singletonList("1"), Collections.emptyList());
            break;
        case "2":
            result = new ProcessUtil.Result(Collections.emptyList(), Collections.singletonList("2"));
            break;
        case "5":
            result = new ProcessUtil.Result(Collections.singletonList("5"), Collections.emptyList());
            break;
    }

    return result;
});
```