# How to properly mock varargs with Mockito

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, variadic-functions

I have this method, "instance" is @Mock

```
instance.lookup(
    SomeClass.class.getField("field").getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class),
    Annotation... annotations
)
```

Signature of that method is exactly this:

```
Object lookup(MyAnnotation resource, Annotation... annotations);
```

Now, that Annotation... value is put there on that mock in runtime in the code I test.

I am trying to Mock it so when I do

```
Mockito.when(instance.lookup....).thenReturn(something);
```

but lookup method always returns null value and exception it thrown (it basically do not return "something" but null)

I was thinking that I have to mock these varargs as well so I modified it to this

```
Mockito.when(instance.lookup(_instance line_, Mockito.any(Annotation[].class)))
```

but it fails telling me that I am using it "raw".

When I use anyVarargs() like this

```
Mockito.when(instance.lookup(_that line_, Mockito.anyVararg()))
```

Mockito.anyVararg() returns Object but I need Annotation[]

Any hint here?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you need `Mockito.<Annotation>anyVararg()` as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2634588/1095318

Comment: it still says I am using it raw. I can not use your example in Mockito.when(instance.lookup, Mockito.<Annotation>anyVararg())

Comment: I have to match the first argument as well ... hmmm. I do not have any idea how to match it really.

Comment: " can not use your example in Mockito.when(instance.lookup, Mockito.<Annotation>anyVararg())" Why ? What is the error ?