# How to mock method with variable parameters eg concatenate(String... messages)

Tags: java, mockito, junit4

How to mock method with variable parameters `concatenate(String... messages)`

If I pass parameters as

```
String[] messages = {"abc"};
Helper helper = mock(Helper.class);
doReturn(someStr).when(helper).concatenate(messages);
```

It won't work.

Comment: Why whould you want to do something like that in the first place?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly match varargs in Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631596/how-to-properly-match-varargs-in-mockito)

Comment: @mike: I am writing junit using mockito and I want to mock concatenate(). I also tried Mockito.<String>anyVararg() but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't see the problem. Let's try it ...

Let's assume we have this class...

```
public class Helper {

    public String concatenate(String...strings) {
        // ...some concat logic, not important
    }

}
```

...and now we want to mock it...

```
@Test
public void testSomething() {

    Helper helper = Mockito.mock(Helper.class);

    Mockito.doReturn("blablub").when(helper).concat(Mockito.anyVararg());

    Assertions.assertThat(helper.concat("bla", "bli")).isEqualTo("blablub");
}
```

And yes, this works. We give it "bla" and "bli", but because we told the mock to return "blablub" in any case, we get that as result. So mocking any vararg is easy enough... We can of course also only check part of the whole vararg, for example...

```
    Mockito.doReturn("blablub").when(helper).concat(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.eq("blub"), Mockito.anyVararg());

    Assertions.assertThat(helper.concat("bli", "blub", "bla", "blu", "blo")).isEqualTo("blablub");
```

...which will return "blablub" as long as then 2nd argument is "blub", no matter what the others are.

Answer (score -1):

Better to use reflection method to initiate string value

FieldUtils.writeField(testClass, "stringVariableName", "value", true);