# Matching varargs in Mockito for unit testing in an overloaded method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, spring-rest

I am not able to mock varargs on an overloaded constructor in Mockito. This is the method I want to test

```
@Override
  public List<User> fetchDataFromExternalService() {
    return Arrays.asList(this.restTemplate.getForObject(URL, User[].class));
  }
```

`User` is a POJO class that has attributes, getters and setters. RestTemplate instance is [Spring's Rest Template.](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html).

This function is an overloaded function and has the the following methods

```
1) public <T> T getForObject(java.lang.String url,
                                    java.lang.Class<T> responseType,
                                    java.lang.Object... uriVariables)
                             throws RestClientException

2) public <T> T getForObject(java.lang.String url,
                                    java.lang.Class<T> responseType,
                                    java.util.Map<java.lang.String,?> uriVariables)
                             throws RestClientException
```

I am trying to mock the first function to return an array of users, but not matter what I try, it always returns `null`. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

My mocking function.

```
User user = new User();
Mockito.when(this.restTemplate.getForObject(
        Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.eq(User[].class), (Object[]) Mockito.any())).thenReturn(new User[] {user});
```

I tried using a custom argument matcher as follows,

```
Mockito.when(this.restTemplate.getForObject(
        Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.eq(User[].class),
        Mockito.argThat(new MyVarargMatcher()))).thenReturn(new User[] {user});
```

but it still returned `null` for me.

```
  class MyVarargMatcher implements ArgumentMatcher<Object[]>, VarargMatcher {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object[] argument) {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

I tried using the approach in this post, but the method is deprecated.

[How to properly match varargs in Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631596/how-to-properly-match-varargs-in-mockito)

https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.7/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#any()

Maven configuration

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class DemoApplicationTests {
    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    @Test
    public void testy() {
        Mockito.when(restTemplate.getForObject(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(), (Object) Mockito.any())).thenReturn("this works");
        Assert.assertEquals("this works", restTemplate.getForObject("hi", String.class, 42, 45));
    }

}
```

Comment: What happens if you don't pass varags to the method.

Comment: I took out the numbers at the end of the method call and it still passes

Answer (score 0):

You are right about [deprecation](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.13.0/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#anyVararg--), but in the same documentation you could find that you should use ArgumentMatchers.any() and [more details about it](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.13.0/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#any--). So the correct example should be:

```
Mockito.when(this.restTemplate.getForObject(Mockito.anyString(),
        Mockito.eq(User[].class), ArgumentMatchers.any())).thenReturn(new User[] {user});
```

If you have varArgs different than Object.class you could specify it to narrow matches `ArgumentMatchers.any(String.class)`.

Working example:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

public class DocTest {
    @Test
    public void testMockito() {
        DocTest doc = mock(DocTest.class);
        when(doc.getDocs(eq(String.class), any(String.class))).thenReturn("success");
        assertEquals("success", doc.getDocs(String.class));
        assertEquals(null, doc.getDocs(Integer.class));
        assertEquals("success", doc.getDocs(String.class, "failed", "failed"));
        assertEquals(null, doc.getDocs(String.class, new Integer(1)));
    }

    public <T> String getDocs(Class<T> clazz, Object... objects){
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: AdditionalMatchers does not show "any" in the method API.

Comment: You are right, copy past mistake. The correct name is `org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any()`.

Comment: Could you share how exactly did you tried? restTemplate should be mocked object. I will update answer with working example.