# Mocked spring bean restTemplate methods returns null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito

I'm working on spring boot application that makes three external api calls from service layer, so while writing the integration tests, I'm trying to override actual `RestTemplate` bean with mocked `RestTemplate` bean and when making the three external API calls I specified to return some data

```
given(this.restTemplate.exchange(ArgumentMatchers.any(), ArgumentMatchers.any(), ArgumentMatchers.any(),
            ArgumentMatchers.isA(new ParameterizedTypeReference<TestData1>() {
            }.getClass()))).willReturn(ResponseEntity.accepted().body(new TestData1()));

    given(this.restTemplate.exchange(ArgumentMatchers.any(), ArgumentMatchers.any(), ArgumentMatchers.any(),
            ArgumentMatchers.isA(new ParameterizedTypeReference<TestData2>() {
            }.getClass()))).willReturn(ResponseEntity.accepted().body(new TestData2()));

    given(this.restTemplate.exchange(ArgumentMatchers.any(), ArgumentMatchers.any(), ArgumentMatchers.any(),
            ArgumentMatchers.isA(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<TestData3>>() {
        }.getClass()))).willReturn(ResponseEntity.accepted().body(Arrays.asList(new TestData3())));
```

But the problem is when ever `restTemplate.exchange` method is called it is returning `null` as response instead of `ResponseEntity` with corresponding body

**TestConfig** class

```
@TestConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Profile("test")
public class TestConfig {

     @Bean
     public RestTemplate restTemplae() {
         return Mockito.mock(RestTemplate.class);
      }
```

**TestClass**

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = { TestConfig.class })
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Profile("test")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class TestClass {

 @Autowired
 private RestTemplate restTemplate;

  @Test
  public void taskTest() {

    //code

    given(this.restTemplate.exchange(ArgumentMatchers.any(), ArgumentMatchers.any(), ArgumentMatchers.any(),
        ArgumentMatchers.isA(new ParameterizedTypeReference<TestData1>() {
        }.getClass()))).willReturn(ResponseEntity.accepted().body(new TestData1()));

given(this.restTemplate.exchange(ArgumentMatchers.any(), ArgumentMatchers.any(), ArgumentMatchers.any(),
        ArgumentMatchers.isA(new ParameterizedTypeReference<TestData2>() {
        }.getClass()))).willReturn(ResponseEntity.accepted().body(new TestData2()));

given(this.restTemplate.exchange(ArgumentMatchers.any(), ArgumentMatchers.any(), ArgumentMatchers.any(),
        ArgumentMatchers.isA(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<TestData3>>() {
    }.getClass()))).willReturn(ResponseEntity.accepted().body(Arrays.asList(new TestData3())));

 //code
  }
```

Comment: `RestTemplate.exchange()` has *many* (8!) overloads! ..are you sure you're mocking the correct one? (please try to mock "more precise" than `any()`)

Comment: that's good point it will try specifying each type, but still this should work right?

Comment: yea... it is "known working" (mocking resttemplate)

Comment: ..and (maybe) you have to watch out for "varargs" (https://stackoverflow.com/q/2631596/592355).

Comment: No luck I tried specifying each type@xerx593

Comment: ..then see, my latter comment: varagrs! ;), try: `given(/*as before, but one additional:*/ , ArgumentMatchers.any())`

Comment: ..i suppose you are trying to mock: [this one](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#exchange-java.lang.String-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-org.springframework.http.HttpEntity-org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference-java.lang.Object...-)

Comment: this one ```public <T> ResponseEntity<T> exchange(java.net.URI url,
                                      HttpMethod method,
                                      @Nullable
                                      HttpEntity<?> requestEntity,
                                      ParameterizedTypeReference<T> responseType)
                               throws RestClientException```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189485/discussion-between-xerx593-and-app).