# How to stub varargs in Mockito to match only one argument

Tags: java, kotlin, mockito

I'd like to stub some code so that a vararg method returns true when one of the arguments matches a specific value. For example, given the existing code that I can't change:

(Using Kotlin here, but I figure this applies to any Java situation.)

```
class Foo {
    fun bar(vararg strings : String) : Boolean {
        // Iterates `strings` and returns true when one satisfies some criteria
    }
}
```

... I want to write stub code similar to this:

```
val foo = Foo()
whenever(foo.bar(eq("AAA"))).thenReturn(true)
```

This works fine when the call is **exactly** `foo.bar("AAA")`.

However, there are times when the code under test makes the call `foo.bar("AAA", "BBB")`, and in those cases, it fails.

How can I revise my stub code so it works when any number of varargs are passed in the call?

**Edit** Flagged as a possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631596); in that case, the scenario contemplates the complete omission of the varargs in the call. Here, I'm trying to match one specific element of the varargs array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to stub your method 2 times. First the least specific stub:

```
val foo = Foo()
whenever(foo.bar(any())).thenReturn(false) // or whatever you want to return/throw here
```

And then the more specific single argument method:

```
whenever(foo.bar(eq("AAA"))).thenReturn(true)
```

---

After your comment you may aswell use something like this (using Java this time):

```
when(foo.bar(any())).thenAnswer(invocation -> {
    for (Object argument : invocation.getArguments()) {
        if ("AAA".equals(argument)) return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

---

And the same in Kotlin

```
whenever(foo.bar(any()).thenAnswer {
    it.arguments.contains("AAA")
}
```

Comment: Thanks! However, this won't work for my situation. As long as "AAA" is one of the args, it should return true. It doesn't have to be the one and only argument in the call.

Comment: @Hugh see my edit, you can just always iterate over the arguments and then check if `"AAA"` was one of them

Comment: Thanks @Lino! Works perfectly. I have an edit pending peer review that adds the Kotlin version of your solution.

Comment: @Hugh I approved your edit, but removed your "Thanks" comments, as you should not put that in the answer. But glad that I could help you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own `matcher` :

```
public class MyVarargMatcher extends ArgumentMatcher<String[]> implements VarargMatcher
{
    private String expectedFirstValue;

    public MyVarargMatcher(String expectedFirstValue)
    {
        this.expectedFirstValue = expectedFirstValue;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object varargArgument) {
        if (varargArgument instanceof String[])
        {
            String[] args = (String[]) varargArgument;
            return Stream.of(args).anyMatch(expectedFirstValue::equals);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then use it like that (Java code) :

```
Foo foo = Mockito.mock(Foo.class);
Mockito.doReturn(true).when(foo).bar(Mockito.argThat(new MyVarargMatcher("AAA")));
```

edited with the op's comment :  *As long as "AAA" is one of the args, it should return true*