# Mocking Overloaded Methoods With Mockito

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, mockito

I am testing some methods that rely on the `getForObject()` method in the `RestTemplate` class.

The `getForObject()` method is overloaded with the signatures`getForObject(String url, Class<T> responseType, Object... uriVariables)` and `getForObject(String url, Class<T> responseType, Map<String, ?>`

I need to stub the method with `Object...` in its arguments to throw an exception but I can not because `Mockito.any()` also encompasses the `Map` type.
Therefore, stubbing the method as `getForObject(Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.any(), Mockito.any()` will point to BOTH methods triggering a compilation error.

Are there any possible workarounds to this problem?

I have already tried using `Mockito.anyObject()` to no avail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what your problem might be, but at this point I might as well just post a working example.

As mentioned before you need to properly specify the type of each parameter, so that mockito can locate the matching method signature.

For the syntax to handle varargs used by older mockito versions, check [`this answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631596/how-to-properly-match-varargs-in-mockito).

```
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
...

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MockitoTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {

        RestTemplate api = Mockito.mock(RestTemplate.class);

        Object obj1 = new Object();
        Object obj2 = new Object();
        Object obj3 = new Object();

        Mockito.when(api.getForObject(any(String.class),any(Class.class), ArgumentMatchers.<Object>any())).thenReturn(obj1);
        Mockito.when(api.getForObject(any(String.class),any(Class.class), any(Map.class))).thenReturn(obj2);
        Mockito.when(api.getForObject(any(URI.class),any(Class.class))).thenReturn(obj3);

        Assert.assertEquals(obj1, api.getForObject("", String.class));
        Assert.assertEquals(obj1, api.getForObject("", String.class, obj1));
        Assert.assertEquals(obj1, api.getForObject("", String.class, obj1, obj2));
        Assert.assertEquals(obj1, api.getForObject("", String.class, obj1, obj2, obj3));
        Assert.assertEquals(obj1, api.getForObject("", String.class, new Object[] {obj1,obj2,obj3}));

        Assert.assertEquals(obj2, api.getForObject("", String.class, new HashMap()));

        Assert.assertEquals(obj3, api.getForObject(new URI(""), String.class));
    }
}
```

For your usecase just replace the `thenReturn` with `thenThrow`.

Answer (score 0):

Varargs can be represented as an array, so you could try this along with specyfing the exact type of the second param:

```
getForObject(Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.any(Class.class), Mockito.any(Object[].class))
```

Comment: `doThrow(mockEx).when(restTemplate).getForObject(Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.any(MyClass.class),Mockito.any(Object[].class));` gave me the error `Can not resolve method getForObject(String, T, T)`

Comment: i think it should be any(Class.class)

Comment: No luck, the stubbed method is never triggered

Comment: But you dont get compilation error anymore?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski No more compilation errors!

Comment: @second still no luck, the stub is not picked up

Comment: you need to add the SUT method and the test method in that case