# how to mock restTemplate getForObject

Tags: junit, mockito

I want to test the `restTemplate.getForObject` method using a mock but having issues. I'm new with Mockito, so I read some blogs about testing restTemplate using Mockito but still can not write a successful test.
The class to test is :

```
package rest;

@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@Service
public class RestClient {

    private String user;
    // from application properties
    private String password;
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public Client getClient(final short cd) {

        restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(new BasicAuthenticationInterceptor(user, password));

        Client client = null;

        try {
            client = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/clients/findClient?cd={cd}",
                    Client.class, cd);
        } catch (RestClientException e) {

            println(e);
        }

        return client;
    }

    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
        return restTemplate;
    }

    public void setRestTemplate(final RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }
}
```

My test class :

```
package test;
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class BatchRestClientTest {


    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @InjectMocks
    private RestClient restClient;

    private MockRestServiceServer mockServer;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void getCraProcessTest() {
        Client client=new Client();
        client.setId((long) 1);
        client.setCd((short) 2);
        client.setName("aaa");

        Mockito
            .when(restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/clients/findClient?cd={cd},
                    Client.class, 2))
            .thenReturn(client);

        Client client2= restClient.getClient((short)2);
        assertEquals(client, client2);
    }

    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
        return restTemplate;
    }

    public void setRestTemplate(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    public RestClient getRestClient() {
        return restClient;
    }

    public void setRestClient(RestClient restClient) {
        this.restClient = restClient;
    }
}
```

It is  returning null and not the expected client, the `restTemplate` for Object class works fine. I want just to write the test . Am I missing something or doing the test wrong way?
Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Do you mean "It is returning null" instead of "It is **not** returning null"?

Comment: yes . updated . thanks

Comment: You're using two different url, one ending with `..?cd={cd}` and the other `...?cd={id}`. Try to using the same one

Comment: updated . thanks . still same problem

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

```java
Mockito.when(restTemplate.getForObject(
    "http://localhost:8080/clients/findClient?cd={id}",
    Client.class,
    new Object[] {(short)2})
).thenReturn(client);
```

The third parameter is a `varargs`.
So you need to wrap into an `Object[]` in the test, otherwise Mockito is not able to match it. Note that this happens automatically in your implementation.

Also:

- You forgot to terminate your `url` (missing closing `"`) in your examples in the question.
   Probably just a typo.
- You used different `url`'s in your implementation in your test: `...?cd={cd}` instead of `...?cd={id}`.
  (As previously pointed out by `@ArnaudClaudel` in the comments).
- You did not define a behaviour for `restTemplate.getInterceptors()`
   so I would expect it to fail with a `NullPointerException`,
   when trying to `add` the `BasicAuthenticationInterceptor`.

---

Additionally you might want to check my answer [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57381132/mocking-overloaded-methoods-with-mockito/57394411#57394411) for another example of how to mock the `getForObject` method. Note that it does not include a case where any of the real parameters would be `null`.