# Trying to mock restClient external API but it is invoking the actual API in java

Tags: spring, mocking, mockito, rest-client, powermockrunner

I am trying to mock restClient external API but it is invoking the actual API instead of mocking it.
Kindly help as I am not sure where I am going wrong.

I tried mocking the call and a few more other things but it didn't work.

```
public class TestService
{
    private static final String EXTERNAL_API = "http://LinktoExternalAPI/";

    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;


    public  Map<String, String> countryCodes()
    {
        Map<String, String> map = new TreeMap<>();

        try
        {
            ResponseEntity<testCountry[]> responseEntity = restTemplate
                    .getForEntity(EXTERNAL_API
                            , testCountry[].class);
            List<testCountry> testCountryList = Arrays.asList(responseEntity.getBody());
            map = testCountryList.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(testCountry::getCode, testCountry::getName));
        }

        catch (HttpClientErrorException | HttpServerErrorException httpClientOrServerExc)
        {

        }

        return map;
    }
}
```

Test case for this is below:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class TestServiceTest
{
    @InjectMocks
    TestService testService;

    @Mock
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    private static final String EXTERNAL_API = "http://LinktoExternalAPI/";

    @Test
    public void testCountryCodes(){

        TestCountry testCountry = new TestCountry();
        testCountry.setCode("JPN");
        testCountry.setName("Japan");

        List<testCountry> testCountryList = new ArrayList<testCountry>();
        testCountryList.add(testCountry);

        Mockito.when(restTemplate.getForEntity(EXTERNAL_API, testCountry[].class)).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity(testCountryList, HttpStatus.OK));
        Map<String, String> result = testService.countryCodes();

        // result is pulling the actual size of the api instead of mocking and sending me testCountryList size.
        <Will mention assertion here>
    }
```

The result is pulling the actual size of the API instead of mocking and sending me `testCountryList` size.

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind the actual API being called is probably that the URL you are mocking is not exactly the same as that being generated at runtime, because of which a mock is not found and actual API is called.
In these cases, you can use `Mockito.any()`.

So the mock code will be `Mockito.when(restTemplate.getForEntity(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any())).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity(testCountryList, HttpStatus.OK));`

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestServiceTest {

  @InjectMocks
  private TestService testService;

  @Mock
  private RestTemplate restTemplate;

  @Test
  public void testCountryCodes(){

    TestCountry testCountry = new TestCountry();
    testCountry.setCode("JPN");
    testCountry.setName("Japan");

    TestCountry[] testCountryList = {
        testCountry
    };

    Mockito.when(restTemplate.getForEntity(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any())).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity(testCountryList, HttpStatus.OK));

    Map<String, String> result = testService.countryCodes();

    // result is pulling the actual size of the API instead of mocking and sending me testCountryList size.

  }
}
```

Also try using `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` instead of `PowerMockRunner.class` since you don't seem to be needing the PowerMock capabilities.

Comment: This is still hitting the actual api .

Comment: I only changed what you mention. I did change only Mockito.when(restTemplate.getForEntity(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any())).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity(testCountryList, HttpStatus.OK));

Comment: Thanks but it is still hitting the actual API. I changed to MockitoJUnitRunner and replaces Mockito.any() with anyString() also.

Comment: I tried the above code in my local and it was working as expected. Please try using the above code as it is instead of copying some portions of it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201604/discussion-between-yash-sugandh-and-rahul).

Answer (score 0):

You are mocking the wrong method definition.

A `getForObject` method with the parameters `String` and `Class` does not exist. You need to define behaviour for [`this`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#getForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object...-) method.

Note that in your case the third parameter (the varargs) is not used, so it defaults to an empty array. However `Mockito` requires this information to mock the correct call.

```java
Mockito.when(restTemplate.getForObject(any(String.class), any(Class.class), ArgumentMatchers.<Object>any()))
       .thenReturn(result);
```

---

For a more complete example check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57394411/11514534).