# Testing method having CompletableFuture.allOf using mockito

Tags: java, mockito, powermockito

I have a method called doParallelThings:

```
public Dummy doParallelThings(Map<String, String> mapp) throws Exception {
        Dummy dummy = new Dummy();

        CompletableFuture<Ans1> one = firstService.getOne(mapp.get("some1"), mapp);
        CompletableFuture<Ans2> two = secondService.getTwo(headersMap.get("some2"), mapp);

        CompletableFuture<Void> combinedFuture = CompletableFuture.allOf(one, two);
        try {
            combinedFuture.get();
            dummy.setOne(one.get());
            dummy.setTwp(two.get());

        } catch (Throwable e) {

        }
        return dummy;
    }
```

Code works fine but when I'm trying to test it, 
`combinedFuture.get();` goes to infinite loop.

Unit test is as below:

```
@Mock
    private CompletableFuture<Void> ans;

@Test
    public void testDoParallelThings() throws Exception {

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(CompletableFuture.class);
        PowerMockito.when(CompletableFuture.allOf(any())).thenReturn(ans);
        when(ans.get()).thenReturn(null);

        Dummy dummy = dummyService. doParallelThings(mockMap);
        assertNotNull(dummy);
    }
```

I have also added `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({CompletableFuture.class})` above the test class.

What am I missing?

Comment: You should mock `firstService.getOne` and `secondService.getTwo` instead, so they return a already completed future.

Comment: I tried that as well, 
```@Mock
    private CompletableFuture<One> mockOneFuture;

    @Mock
    private One mockOne;

when(firstService.getOne(any(), any())).thenReturn(mockOneFuture);
        mockOneFuture.complete(mockOne);```

Comment: As your method (`CompletableFuture.allOf`) has a varargs parameter, you need to mock it arcordingly. Check this [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2634588/11514534).

Answer (score 5):

`when(firstService.getOne(any(), any())).thenReturn(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(mockOne));`

solved my problem

Comment: So instead of mocking the static method `CompletableFuture.allOf` you changed your test to use real `CompletableFutures` instead and mocked the first and second service instead. That is probably the btter choice for a simple unit test.

Comment: Have almost exactly the same code but the moment I add CompletableFuture.completedFuture in the below line of code it gives me below error. Doesn't come when I remove it but then my Future is incomplete & in loop.
Is it possible to share ur code so that I can check if I'm missing something?
    
when(firstService.getOne(any(),any())).thenReturn(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(mockOne));

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at com.myCompany.TestClass.testMethodNotNull(TestClass.java:52)

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing